# FFMPEG How To use Concat demuxer with a crossfade

Tags: ffmpeg, video, concatenation, visual-effects

I've got the `concat` demuxer to work well using this code: `ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i videoList.txt -c copy output.mp4` where `videoList.txt` is a file containing this type of data:

```
file BohemianRhapsodyLeadElecGuitar.mp4 
inpoint 0
outpoint 3
file BohemianRhapsodyLeadElecGuitar.mp4
inpoint 3
outpoint 6
file BohemianRhapsodyBackingVocals.mp4
inpoint 6
outpoint 9
file BohemianRhapsodyBackingVocals.mp4
inpoint 9
outpoint 12
file BohemianRhapsodyBackingVocals.mp4
inpoint 12
outpoint 15
file BohemianRhapsodyBackingVocals.mp4
inpoint 15
outpoint 18
file BohemianRhapsodyBackingVocals.mp4
inpoint 18
outpoint 21
file BohemianRhapsodyPiano.mp4
inpoint 21
outpoint 24
file BohemianRhapsodyPiano.mp4
inpoint 24
outpoint 27
file BohemianRhapsodyBackingVocals.mp4
inpoint 27
outpoint 30
file BohemianRhapsodyBackingVocals.mp4
inpoint 30
outpoint 33
file BohemianRhapsodyLeadVocal.mp4
inpoint 33
outpoint 36
...
```

However, I want to add a `0.5s` cross-fade transition between each of the video segments specified in the `videoList.txt`. I was wondering what would be the best approach for this task?